# how to upload bulk json data on elasticsearch sever using curl?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using ES version 6.1.3.
I am trying to upload **bulk** of json data using curl cmd on windows 7
here's my cmd:

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/fooditems/item/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @food_items.json
```

I tried an alternate cmd for it which are

```
curl -H "Content-Type:application/x-ndjson" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/fooditems/item/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @food_items.json

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/fooditems/item/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary @food_items.json
```

and here is my sample data of food_items.json

```
> {"index":{"_index":"fooditems","_type":"item","_id":0}}
> {"id":"0","name":"Jowar Puffed"}
> {"index":{"_index":"fooditems","_type":"item","_id":1}}
> {"id":"1","name":"Uamp and tea"}
> {"index":{"_index":"fooditems","_type":"item","_id":2}}
> {"id":"2","name":"Banana Chips"}
```

I have provided mapping for data through Kibana is as-

```
POST /fooditems/item
{
  "mappings": {
    "_default_":{
      "properties": {
        "id":{
          "type" :"text"
        },
        "name":{
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have been encountered errors

> "The bulk request must be terminated by a newline [\n]"
>
> illegal_argument_exception

i am not sure what it's trying to say.
pls help me out here.

Comment: You need to make sure to add a newline at the end of your `food_items.json` file

Comment: {"index":{"_index":"fooditems","_type":"item","_id":0}}\n
{"id":"0","name":"Jowar Puffed"}\n
{"index":{"_index":"fooditems","_type":"item","_id":1}}\n
{"id":"1","name":"Uamp and tea"}\n
{"index":{"_index":"fooditems","_type":"item","_id":2}}\n
{"id":"2","name":"Banana Chips"}\n
Is it correct?

Comment: Try it out and you'll see :-)

Comment: i tried as you said but it still showing same error.
Is it my cmd is crct?

curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/fooditems/item/_bulk" --data-binary @food_items.json

Comment: The fiel must not contain a verbatim `\n` character, but simply a carriage return after the last line. Can you gist your file?

Comment: https://github.com/Kunj-Choksi/food-items/blob/master/food_items.json
Here it is

Comment: You should have an empty line at line 41

Comment: Yeah! found it.
Thnak you so much!